# Impala list all dates between 2 dates

Tags: impala

Can **HUE Impala** create a column which shows all dates between a specified start and end dates?
I want to list a column with date values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sql.

```
select a.Date_Range
from (
    select date1 - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a) + (1000 * d.a) ) DAY as Date_Range
    from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as d
) a
where a.Date_Range <= date2
```

Explanation -
You first create a range of numbers. And then add it to the date1 to get a range. Then you can pick your date range less than date2.